# Dialogflow (Custom Payload and Webhook Enabled)

Tags: javascript, android-intent, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I have noticed that you cannot have a custom payload on one intent and enable Webhook on that intent.[image]
Anyone else encountered this issue? I have contacted Google Support, but received no response from them. I tried to set it in the fulfillment, but I want to have two custom payloads instead of one.

Comment: when there is enabled webhook it supposes to get responses from webhook

Answer (score 2):

The Dialogflow responses section and the fulfillment webhook are two different ways to do the same thing. Both can include custom payload, but you have to decide on using one or the other. If your are using a webhook your payload has to be included in that webhooks response.

Comment: how can we add custom payload in webhook response? i have tried to add it in `fulfillmentMessages` but that did not work

Comment: @sid8491 Check out the [WebhookResponse.payload](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/WebhookResponse) field.

Comment: oh yes, i got it now, i was supposed to send an array which will consist `payload`, but i was sending the payload dict directly.... thanks for the help. :)